# Generating an xml document: JSP or Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This [servlet or jsp] must return an XML document [for future processing by my web-app].
That is not intended for end-users.

What is a better design: write a JSP or an XML ?

p.s. What I don't like about jsp is that every system admin can see your java code.

p.p.s If that'd be a jsp, than it must be capable to be autowired by Spring. Is it as easy to do as with servlets?

Comment: That system admin concern is a non-argument. If one would like to reveal the source, one would always go as far enough to reveal it. Java classes are decompileable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a servlet for this in combination with a Javabean-to-XML serializer, such as  [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/), etc.

XStream is [pretty easy](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Person person = personDAO.find(request.getParameter("personId"));
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    new XStream().toXML(person, response.getWriter());
}
```

No need to hassle with template text, so also no need for JSP.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, XML documents should be generated using a proper XML tool chain and not a template. This strongly suggests using a servlet since the primary advantage of JSP is that it is template orientated.

Answer (score 2):

JSP's generate characters, servlets bytes.  For XML character encodings to work correctly you need bytes, hence servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that must be a Servlet.

In my case it has to make DB calls, extract data, process it.

That is not a kind of operations a JSP is to do.

Comment: JSP is quite capable of doing those things.

Comment: @David Dorward  yes, 'cause basically jsp & servlet are the same thing ;)